# Cruise control only works up to 110 km/h

Tags: toyota, cruise-control

I have a 2010 Toyota Estima Hybrid, that was imported from Japan into UK. One thing that bothers me slightly is that the cruise control seems to have a top speed limit of about 110 km/h.  The dash has been converted to UK standards (i.e. miles) - so the max I can set the cruise control to is about 68-69 mph.  If the car is moving faster than that (say, 70 mph), the cruise control simply doesn't engage.  If I engage it at 65-67 mph then attempt to increase the speed, it'll increase to about 68-69 max (this is the equivalent of about 110 km/h).

While this isn't a big issue in UK (I'm ok doing 69 instead of 70), this meant that the cruise control was pretty much useless in France where the motorway speed limit is 130 km/h. I really didn't feel like going 20 km/h below the speed limit.

The car does happily go 130 km/h - but the cruise control just won't engage at that speed.

Does anyone know how this limit is implemented?  Is is possible to deactivate/change it?

Comment: May well be a setting unique to the market it was built for - one disadvantage of purchasing outside your own market. Of course you only do 130km/h on a track :)

Comment: @SolarMike I do 130 km/h on a motorway in France, where this is perfectly legal :)

Comment: In France 138 is usually fine :) at least when I cruise Grenoble to Calais only stopping for fuel once...

Comment: Yep - and I'd prefer to use cruise control engaged at 130 rather than keep pushing my foot onto the accelerator pedal for several hours straight.

Comment: So back to the first part of my comment - can you get a UK ecu from a scrappie? and test?

Comment: @SolarMike That's the main issue - this model is only sold in Japan, hence the need to import.

Comment: So that engine is unique?

Comment: There are companies that reprogram ECU's. Assuming the cruise control top speed is just a variable, they must be able to change that.

Comment: My car, albeit an imported JDM Subaru definitely has cruise control speed parameters in the ECU software maps. This is viewable in the open source Rom Raider editor after downloading data from the car. I would think this would also be the case for your car so Toyota tuners could adjust it.

Comment: A little Google-fu reveals that Japanese car manufacturers voluntarily restrict the cruise control maximum speed on cars destined for the domestic Japanese market to 112 km/hr.

Comment: From WWII-2016, there was no speed limit in Japan higher than 100 km/h. There are currently tens of km with 120 km/h limits. It often makes sense with Japan's mountainous geography and dense cities necessitating narrow lanes and curves.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the actuator has reached the end of its travel. There could be extra play in the linkage. If you tighten up any extra free play at the closed throttle position, then the actuator would have more travel at the wide open position.

Comment: This seems very unlikely for a 2010 car, a hybrid no less.